# R-Tree indexing in Core Data ... backwards compatibility pre-iOS 11?

Tags: ios, core-data, spatial, r-tree

I noticed that there's R-Tree indexing with Core Data on iOS 11. If this index gets created, is the model then incompatible with lower iOS versions? Or, is it simply ignored?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchindexelementtype/2887046-rtree

Answer (score 0):

Yes, then the model is incompatible. The only thing I didn't found out is how to compile the model for a target lower than iOS 11 to make it compatible with the old world as Apple states in its [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html).

My workaround is now to let the SDK automatically infer a mapping model:

```
 NSDictionary *pscOptions = @{
            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption       : @YES,
            NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{ @"journal_mode" : @"WAL"}//iOS >=7 Default behaviour
    };

[self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       configuration:nil
                                                                 URL:[self sourceStoreURL]
                                                             options:pscOptions
                                                               error:&error]
```